# Adaptation of argument list by inserting () has been deprecated

Tags: scala

I'm just in the process of upgrading from Scala 2.10.x to 2.11.2 and I'm receiving the following warning with the following code:

```
  override def validateKey(key: String): Either[InvalidKeyError, Unit] = 
    keys.contains(key) match {
      case true => Right()
      case false => Left(InvalidKeyError(context, key))
    }
```

> Adaptation of argument list by inserting () has been deprecated: this
>   is unlikely to be what you want. signature: Right.apply[A, B](b: B):
>   scala.util.Right[A,B] given arguments:  after adaptation:
>   Right((): Unit)

I am able to solve this by changing the "true" case statement to:

```
case true => Right(()) //() is a shortcut to a Unit instance
```

Is this the proper way to address this warning?

**Edit**: perhaps a "why we have to do this now" type answer would be appropriate, my cursory investigation seems to indicate that Scala inserting "Unit" when it thinks it needs to causes *other problems*

Comment: Old question, I know, but why not use `Option[InvalidKeyError]`? Or perhaps `Try[Unit]`, since you're returning an error?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Automatic `Unit` inference [has been deprecated in scala 2.11](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/3260), and the reason behind this is that it can lead to confusing behavior, especially for people learning the language.

Here's an example

```
class Foo[T](value: T)
val x = new Foo
```

This should not compile, right? You are calling the constructor with no arguments, where one is required. Surprisingly, until scala 2.10.4 this compiles just fine, with no errors or warnings.

And that's because the compiler inferred a `Unit` argument, so it actually replaced your code with

```
val x = new Foo[Unit](()) // Foo[Unit]
```

As the newly introduced warning message says, *this is unlikely to be what you want*.

Another famous example is this

```
scala> List(1,2,3).toSet()
// res1: Boolean = false
```

calling `toSet()` should be a compile-time error, since `toSet` does not take arguments, but the compiler desperately tries to make it compile, ultimately interpreting the code as

```
scala> List(1,2,3).toSet.apply(())
```

which means: test whether `()` belongs to the set. Since it's not the case, you get a `false`!

So, starting from scala 2.11, you have to be explicit if you want to pass `()` (aka `Unit`) as an argument. That's why you have to write:

```
Right(())
```

instead of

```
Right()
```

---

*examples taken from [Simplifying Scala — The Past, Present and Future](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umUIkMQlzNk) by Simon Ochsenreither.*

Comment: Is there some link for "Automatic Unit inference has been deprecated in scala 2.11"? Also the "Past, Present and Future" link is rotten and I did not find it anywhere, I am not sure what can be done about it now :(

Comment: added a link to the PR that introduced the deprecation. Simon's video seems lost :(

Comment: ah no, found! Edited the link ;)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it should be `Right(())`. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 4):

My explanation is that since the `Right.apply` is polymorphic it can take all kind of parameters, doing `Right()` means passing in a `Unit` and the compiler simply advise you that maybe that's not what you want, he doesn't know that this is what you actually want.

If you see your deprecate message it states:

> ... after adaptation: Right((): Unit)

Which means that the compiler has automatically decided that you are passing in a `Unit`, since this is kinda like `void` he doesn't really likes it, specifically passing in a `Unit` like `()` explicitly tells the compiler that you do want a `Unit` there. Anyway seems a new deprecation form scala 2.11, I can't reproduce this on 2.10.4.