# Callback that takes and returns Unit

Tags: scala

I have a function that takes a unit callback as a parameter, i.e. a callback that takes and returns `Unit`. If I define my function like this:

```
def myFunction (callback: Unit => Unit) = {
    callback();
}
```

then I get a warning stating that: `Adaptation of argument list by inserting () has been deprecated`. Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25354165/5397009), I tried changing my code to:

```
def myFunction (callback: Unit => Unit) = {
    callback;
}
```

which doesn't work (my callback is not called), or to:

```
def myFunction (callback: Unit => Unit) = {
    callback (());
}
```

which works but is ugly. Is there a way to avoid the double parentheses? Maybe by changing the `Unit => Unit` parameter type to something else that means "a function that takes no parameters" instead of "a function that takes one parameter or type `Unit`"?

Comment: maybe it doesn't need to take unit? `def myFunction (callback: => Unit) = callback`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adaptation of argument list by inserting () has been deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351988/adaptation-of-argument-list-by-inserting-has-been-deprecated)

Comment: Note that a body of `callback` where its type is `Unit => Unit`, simply returns a `Unit => Unit` function. You need to pass `()`, i.e. of type `Unit`, to get a `Unit` value back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're most likely looking for is a function that simply takes no parameters. You also don't need to explicitly type `;` at the end of every line.

```
def myFunction (callback: () => Unit) = callback()
```

This is not the same as a call-by-name parameter.

Answer (score 0):

## Call by name parameter

Use call by name parameter. Call by name parameter gets executed only when it is explicitly called by name like function.

```
def myFunction (callback: => Unit) = callback
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> def myFunction (callback: => Unit) = callback
myFunction: (callback: => Unit)Unit

scala> myFunction(println("helloworld"))
helloworld

scala> myFunction { println("foo"); println("bar") }
foo
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
object CallUnit {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    myFunction(cbk)
  }
  def myFunction(callback: => Unit) = {
    callback
  }  
  def cbk {
    println("Call me maybe")
  }
}
```